# typescript utility type to access object properties with dot notation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a working example, but, with a TS error. I cannot understand the solution to satisfy typescript error `Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'`.

```
type PropertyAccessor<ObjectType, Key extends keyof ObjectType> = Key extends string
  ? ObjectType[Key] extends Record<string, unknown>
    ? `${Key}.${PropertyAccessor<ObjectType[Key], keyof ObjectType[Key]>}`
    : Key
  : never;

type NestedObjectType<T> = {
  [K in PropertyAccessor<T, keyof T>]: K extends `${infer Head}.${infer Rest}`
    ? Head extends keyof T
      ? Rest extends PropertyAccessor<T[Head], keyof T[Head]>
        ? NestedObjectType<T[Head]>[Rest]
        : never
      : never
    : K extends keyof T
    ? T[K]
    : never;
};

function accessProperty<T, K extends keyof NestedObjectType<T>>(obj: T, accessor: K): NestedObjectType<T>[K] {
  return obj[accessor];
}

const obj = { name: 'cory', profile: { emails: ['cory@gmail.com', 'cory@yahoo.com'], age: 37 } };

// Typescript infers the "age" variable as a number type correctly
const age = accessProperty(obj, 'profile.age');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUBBAxuiBnbC4A8A8gEYBWE6wAKuBADRQDSEIUEAHsBAHYAm2KAGtWCAGZRSFKrUgA+KAF5mrdl14Co2YHACWPAOYAoKFAD8k8pRp0A2ixABdNd36CASpXx8C2vYcYAVx4hHgQAdx45E1NzKAADABIAbwcAXwA6FPgkCBQQDCxcfGIrGTsHR0YREHFLaRtIe1ZHOTT4mNMALhUQGJ6eCAA3PIBuIyNQSCgAORxuPilrWQgCagVlZJj7KH1YRGQ0TBw8Qmpq0Ql1xx6mFw1BJOT9MTyoAAkIAEM+TJSXt6ebTtTpxT4-e5uYSXKDUUGmCxA4CQzQ5Q4FY7FM62cF8KrQ2pXHHfPHRWLkuJzbQQRZlRqrajEn6tWxIxzw2IDYZ5DlckZwUG3FGCGp1OHkiyMpjs8l8sZGNLjIxiYJUXQIHhQL6Y7BovKgNaMO6cVyaUUSKkLJblSBrORyAAUCHIPXOWp1+FuAEoepaadb6Xb7M4tqY4BBgIE4JrnWRbNqiqdHOM0hN0BrtFBY0ooMkoDwvgBbCA9ADk6bgIFLjDAiDEugANiXc+xC19G9gerZy-gQAABAxtxsZdOF6tQHuVvsgL4ACwQCBHCDH+K+BmbAGYAOxQNK7pUAegPsLo2HQejAyIB4Z4WCgYnwUAARGuIE+oEMvnoviQm1p54EDZ8FAJDQF8+aBIWoFwFAUwQEY6Y8Jmr45gmJx6vkTrkIwpa1uIjYQBkr6ll6SpAA)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually to fix the broken `function accessProperty()` implementation, here is the fix:

```
function accessProperty<T, K extends keyof NestedObjectType<T>>(obj: T, accessor: K): NestedObjectType<T>[K] | undefined {
  const pathParts = accessor.split('.');
  let result: any = obj;

  for (const pathPart of pathParts) {
    if (typeof result === 'object' && result !== null) {
      result = result[pathPart];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  return result as NestedObjectType<T>[K];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUBBAxuiBnbC4A8A8gEYBWE6wAKuBADRQDSEIUEAHsBAHYAm2KAGtWCAGZRSFKrUgA+KAF5mrdl14Co2YHACWPAOYAoKFAD8k8pRp0A2ixABdNd36CASpXx8C2vYcYAVx4hHgQAdx45E1NzKAADABIAbwcAXwA6FPgkCBQQDCxcfGIrGTsHR0YREHFLaRtIe1ZHOTT4mNMALhUQGJ6eCAA3PIBuIyNQSCgAORxuPilrWQgCagVlZJj7KH1YRGQ0TBw8Qmpq0Ql1xx6mFw1BJOT9MTyoAAkIAEM+TJSXt6ebTtTpxT4-e5uYSXKDUUGmCxA4CQzQ5Q4FY7FM62cF8KrQ2pXHHfPHRWLkuJzbQQRZlRqrajEn6tWxIxzw2IDYZ5DlckZwUG3FGCGp1OHkiyMpjs8l8sZGNLjIxiYJUXQIHhQL6Y7BovKgNaMO6cVyaUUSKkLJblSBrORyAAUCHIPXOWp1+FuAEoepaadb6Xb7M4AD5QYJ8CBifQ0qBbUzoDXaKBgL7AAAWMC+KEEym1RVOGWwYAANrpgA6AOQZSte8amEsQZFwHCBEvAHpfHhsZTOshK0xifBQB2JnjJ1MZrMoKB1SeZ7PAbBeuOg3QSB1TCB1FvYNvIxSHqCVvvWStQABkF6gu-3UAAhEeeG2Syv4xTb+2lDfW+3bPPp2ARx61iNJ2BLbBoHfckW2AQI4E1CMoxjPgQNMNIYgwmJYPgzVP2RL5BD9WkGhWINpXGLCjDHZM+2-ZIoB4L4AFsIB6StEzgEBK0YMBEGjRsegYiBmK+XQIJ6WwOPwEAAAEDFE8SMkTZieOPTi5JAL50wQBBlIQVT8S+Aw2KgABmAB2KAwMVCYAHo7NhOhsHQPQwGRAEWx4LAoCHOAoAAImMiAAqgIZs10L4SEbLQdLbPgoBIaAvkYwJmKS-yt2opMCJM798xOPV8idchGErPjxHEiAMmC2slRohBGwyEsEAMB1gq9CYgA)